# "Since the time" or "from the time"? What should it be?

Tags: word-choice

> I waited for a word from you **since** the time I got the news that you had fled.

or

> I waited for a word from you **from** the time I got the news that you had fled.

Please help. Since or From?

Comment: No significant difference on any level.

Either way, it's almost certain that you meant *I have waited…*

Answer (score 1):

**Since** Besides, I would suggest using " I have been waiting for a word from you" instead of " I waited..." as this is a continuing action. Also, "the time" seems a bit redundant to me.

I have been waiting for a word from you since  I got the news that you had fled.

Comment: Thanks! But somehow I still feel dubious about the whole since vs from thing.

Comment: @YuvrajKumar  Here's my limited understanding: when used as preposition, "since" refers to the period between [the time mentioned] and [now]; while "from" is often used with "to" to describe the period of an event(such as from 7 p.m. to 10 p.m.). As "waiting" in your sentence is an action that's ongoing, "since" is preferred here with a hint of [now]. In other cases, "from" could also indicate the spacial start point like "from China to Russia", which I recommend referring to a dictionary.

Comment: 'Although I waited for a word from you since the time I got the news that you had fled, it still felt unreal to receive your letter yesterday.'

What about this sentence? Is the word since correct here?

Comment: Yes, I think it's grammatically correct.

Comment: I would still use progressive, in this case the past perfect progressive: "Although I had been waiting for a word from you since the time I got the news that you had fled, it still felt unreal to receive your letter yesterday." You can indeed also use *from* instead of *since*, unless you omit "the time." Then you have to use *since*. Also, be careful to avoid ambiguities with *since*; it can have either the meaning "because" or "from the time that."